# How do I retrieve multiple records by categoryId with Angular 2 (typescript)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to retrieve multiple values based on the categoryId

Here's  my code

// mock-data instead of json

```
private recipes: Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe('recipe-a1', 'breakfast'),
    new Recipe('recipe-a2', 'breakfast'),
    new Recipe('recipe-a3', 'breakfast'),
    new Recipe('recipe-a4', 'lunch')
  ];
```

// recipe.service.ts

**// is this correct? how would I retrieve multiple records using the categoryId?**

```
getRecipesByCategoryId(categoryId: string) {
        return this.recipes[categoryId]; 
    }
```

// Here's my component recipe.component.ts
**// ERROR: this.recipes is undefined**

```
constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipesByCategoryId('breakfast'); 
} // is this correct?
```

// Recipe object

```
export class Recipe {
  constructor(public name: string,
              public categoryId: string){}
}
```

Comment: return this.recipes.filter(item => item.id.categoryId(args[0]) !== -1);

Answer (score 3):

You could apply filter over `recipes` based on `categoryId` param

```
getRecipesByCategoryId(categoryId: string) {
    return this.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.categoryId === categoryId); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pankaj! Works perfectly :)

Comment: @atef Glad to help you, Thanks :)